# Where to find a Free Open Source SSL for IIS, and how to install it

Tags: open-source, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm looking for a free Open Source SSL Toolkit where I can install SSL's on my staging server for testing.

I checked out [OpenSSL.org](http://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Aopenssl.org+%22iis%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) but was unable to find anything for IIS.

Does anyone have any idea where I can find such a thing?

Comment: Are you looking for a free SSL Certificate?

Comment: Yup, I'm gonna hopefully be able to use a free cert since this isn't production, just staging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://cert.startcom.org/ offers free certificates and they work with all modern browsers.

Comment: This looks promising too https://certify.webprofusion.com/

Answer (score 0):

IIS already has all the SSL capabilities you should need built-in.

Here's how to configure it for [IIS 6.0](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_ssl_on_your_website_with_iis.htm) and [IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-setup-ssl-on-iis-70/).